# Remove .txt from string in C

Tags: c

I would like to display the names of files without their .txt extension. I already have the file + extension stored from dir->d_name.

It made sense in my head to do it the following way:

```
char filename[size]; //assume this already contains name followed by.txt
filename[size-4] = '\0';
```

I've attempted this, but I am still getting the name with its extension. Perhaps I don't fully understand how the null terminator works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: filename[len(filename) - 4] = '\0';

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Only works if `size` is the same as `strlen(filename)`. If `size` is 200, and the filename is `hello.txt`, well then I think you can see the problem. I would suggest using `strstr` to find the `.txt`.

Comment: @orlp I understand your concern, but is that really necessary for such a simple question?

Comment: @Lance_P it would be nice. You have two answers already, did you check them? :)

Comment: @gsamaras Yes. My problem is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @user3386109 Worse -- if strlen(filename)==sizeof(filename), he put his null terminator outside his buffer and stomped on whatever's adjacent on the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
filename[size-4] = '\0';
```

will not work, since size is not (necessarily) the length of the string.

Try:

```
filename[strlen(filename) - 4] = '\0';
```

---

Minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 20

int main(void) {
  char filename[SIZE] = "test.txt";
  printf("%s\n", filename);
  // -4 for .txt
  filename[strlen(filename) - 4] = '\0';
  printf("%s\n", filename);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ./a.out 
test.txt
test
```

PS - You may want to check if *.txt* really exists.

---

Or<sup>*</sup>, by using [strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/), you could do this and check if *.txt* actually exists:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
  char str[] = "test.txt";
  char *pch;
  pch = strstr(str, ".txt");
  if(pch) // if's body won't execute if .txt is absent
    *pch = '\0';
  puts(str);
  return 0;
}
```

*<sub>as @user3386109 said</sub>

Comment: The `strstr` is not a great solution.  What if your filename is "filename.txt.tar.gz" or "I love .txt files"?

Comment: @user3386109 thanks! Yes, that will work. :) indiv good thing then I proposed two approached. :) (seriously now, yes of course, I am just providing the basis here. Moreover, OP stated an assumption on that.)

Answer (score 0):

Trying doing

```
strncopy(noExt_string, filename, strlen(filename) - 4)
```

This should copy the contents of filename in to noExt_string without the last 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print the filename without the .txt extension then you can do it without change the string.

```
write(1, filename, strlen(filename) - 4);
```